# How to pass values for options arguments when running a Dataflow app in Eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I try to test my first Dataflow app by running it in Eclipse.

When I try to pass 4 values for the arguments on "Run Configuration" on "Arguments" tab as following:

```
projects/poc/subscriptions/poc-TestApp1   poc  myDataSet  my_logs
```

I get the error:

> Argument 'projects/poc/subscriptions/poc-TestApp1' does not begin
>   with '--'

adding `--` to all arguments produced a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems that you have custom argument parsing code in your program (I suppose you're extracting your arguments as `args[0]`, `args[1]` etc. in your `main()` function?), but still use `PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)` to configure the options for Dataflow itself.

Dataflow does not support this mixed way of specifying command-line arguments - you need to define your own PipelineOptions to represent your configuration parameters, and specify them prefixed with `--`.

Please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) for details, in particular [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#creating-custom-options) for creating custom options.

Comment: Thanks.  On the link you provided I saw that  cmd-line arguments should follow this format:  --<option>=<value>, and applying that format took care of that problem.